# Sparse multiplication, MATLAB: only certain elements

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Is there any built-in or efficient way to calculate only certain elements in a matrix multiplication `A*B = C in MATLAB`? 
For example, calculate only the elements of `C, (i,j)` such that `D(i,j) = 1`, for some other matrix.

Comment: So efficiently compute `C(i,j) = A(i,:) * B(:,j)` only for `(i,j)` pairs matching `D(i,j) == 1`, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach:

```
[ii, jj] = find(D==1);
result = sum(A(ii,:).'.*B(:,jj), 1);
```